# Changing bounds of integrals

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution

If I have:

$$\int_{L}^{\infty }e^{\dfrac{-(x-\sigma \sqrt{T})^2}{2}}\,dx$$

let $y = x - \sigma \sqrt{T}$

$$\int_{L - \sigma \sqrt{T}}^{\infty }e^{\dfrac{-y^2}{2}} \, dy$$

Why does the lower bound change in the new integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower bound was from $x=L$, after the transformation, we get $y|_{x=L}=x-\sigma\sqrt T |_{x=L} = L-\sigma \sqrt T $, so the lower bound goes from $y=L-\sigma\sqrt T$.

Intuitively, you're performing the integration according to a new variable $y$, which is just a translation of $x$, so you need to translate the boundaries appropriately. Of course, the infinite boundary will remain infinity.

Comment: That's what I figured, but I couldn't explain mathematically why the bounds were changing.

Comment: In short, the boundaries are particular values of the integration variable $x$. If the variable is substituted with a formula, the bounds have to follow since they are $x$-s.  But infinity isn't a number. It is actually a shorthand which denotes a limit: $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ actually means $\displaystyle\lim_{s\to\infty}\int_0^s f(x)dx$. So additional reasoning has to be applied to transform limit bounds: the limit in one variable has to change to a limit in another variable. We know that if $x$ grows large, then $x + b$ grows large (linear transform, and x did not change sign).